# The rails process of the new and edit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails application, when you call the new method (e.g users/new) and the edit method (users/edit) what does rails do in the background? does it the new lead to the create and the edit lead to the update?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<%= form_for @user do |f| %>`, Rails determine which URL and HTTP method to use (in order to lead to `create` or `update` action) by calling `persisted?` method on `@user` object. If it returns `false`, `create` form will be generated. If it's `true`, the form will lead to `update` action.